# "extends boolean" and give default?

Tags: typescript

```js
type Test<T extends boolean = false> = {
  a?: T;
};
const t: Test = {
  a: true,
};
```

The code above complains about `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.ts(2322)`

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

=========== update ===========

Thanks for the comments and answers!

I thought when declaring a generic type, that `T` is determined by the property that was given the `T`.

So if I assign `a: true`, that `T` becomes `true`; if I assign `a: false` or `undefined`, the `T` uses the default `false`.

Just like what function parameters and the defaults do.

So I have to explicitly tell ts `Test<true>`?

---

What about this use case:

```js
type RecursiveType<OK extends boolean = false> = { // 1
  isOK: OK;
  property: OK extends true ? ("a"|"b") : 0;
  children?: Array<RecursiveType>; // 2
}

const recursive:RecursiveType = {
  isOK: true;
  property: 'a',
  children: [
    {
      isOK: false,
      property: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

How to declare the type properly so my editor (vscode) give correct hints depends on `isOK`?

Comment: Why is the default type for `T` set to `false`?

Comment: `const t: Test<true> = ...`? Otherwise you get the default, which is indeed incompatible.

Comment: This question kinda feels like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300259/generic-typescript-with-optional-extends

Comment: `t` is declared as the default (`Test`), and immediately set as the opposite of the default (`a: true`). There is no way to set the type of something as one thing, and then immediate set it as something else. You'd get a similar error with `type Test<T extends number = 0> = { a?: T; }; const t: Test = { a: "b" };`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass any type to the generic it will use the default value, here `false`.

You can either do

```
const t: Test = { // no type === will only accept false
  a: false,
};
```

or

```
const t: Test<true> = { // will only accept the type passed to the generic
  a: true,
};
```

Comment: Another way to say this is that `const t: Test = {` is exactly the same as `const t: Test<false> = {`